# Отследить андроид-приложение

Tags: apk, android, java

Возможно ли отследить, к каким ресурсам телефона обращается установленное андроид-приложение?
API-запросы, файлы и прочее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Засуньте APK в [VirusTotal](http://www.virustotal.com) и получите [отчетик типа такого](https://www.virustotal.com/ru/file/e29bfe50a77af88298ea9a95cbf4976d55313e23b61b1735b644830af2f98d5c/analysis/1413210014/).

Как нетрудно увидеть, там все разложено по полочкам - какие пермишены есть и какие вызовы API использует приложение, какие активити запускает, какие файлы открывает, удаляет и проч., проч.

Comment: @Barmaley, а вот я использую [An(d)rubis](https://anubis.iseclab.org/). Этот "зверь" полностью потрошит приложение и очень тщательно проверяет его. Результаты очень подробно расписываются (онлайн или в загружаемом варианте).

Answer (score 1):

Если Вас интересует, использует ли приложение потенциальное опасные API (например, отправка смс, работа с камерой и т.д.), то для этого есть разрешения (permissions). Они определены в файле AndroidManifest.xml. Андроид всегда при установке приложения показывает список разрешений и просит пользователя согласиться с ними.